# Saving mongoose query data in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

so im basically trying to build an array with the findById on a mongoose model in a loop function. I have three basic models Company, User and Dog. A user can add companys and dogs and a user can add its dogs to a company.

A Company with added dogs looks something like this:

```
{
 _id: ObjectId(...),
 checkedInDogs: [ObjectId(...), ObjectId(...) ObjectId(...)] // ids from dogs,
 addedByUser: ObjectId(...) // user id
 name: ...,
 ...
}
```

I want a endpoint which gives me the users, which added the dogs to the company

At first i want all created Companys from a registered user. If the user added more companys then one, i have to map those. After that, i have to loop over the checkedInDogs Array to get the user which added the dog.

```
router.get("/employees", auth, (reg, res) => {
  Company.find({addedByUser: reg.user.id})
    .then(companys => {
      companys.map(comp => {
        comp.checkedInDogs.map(dogId => {
          Dog.findById(dogId)
            .populate("addedByUser", "-_id -email -password -loggedInAs")
            .exec()
            .then(data => {
              console.log(data);
            });
        });
      });
    });
});
```

The console function does print the dogs with the user information, but i don't really know how to save them in an array to write a response function, so i can use it in my frontend.

I know i'm here in the async nodejs hell and but can't find a way to work this

Comment: you need an [aggregation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate) with a lookup and filter between the `dog` `company` and `user`

Comment: Hi, can you add some example input data and the expected result? Do you want to get a list of dogs which is inside the company which was created by a specific user?

Comment: yes, i'll do tomorrow. And to your second question: i want the users, which checked the dogs in to the company. I got the information from the user from the last dog query by populating them. @SuleymanSah

Comment: I think this approach to get my data is to primitive, i'll look into the aggregate function. Database knowledge is a little rusted